# My home server (ubuntu 16.04) has two IP addresses and I dont really know why

Tags: networking

Okay so I don't really know why but my home server has two ip addresses I know that a while back I setup a static IP for it but now having two causes trouble.

output from  `nmcli device show enp2s0`

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveCo                                  nnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.10.10.42/24
IP4.ADDRESS[2]:                         10.10.10.110/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.10.10.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt =                                   1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.10.10.110
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[3]:                             10.10.10.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::1299:e53:48be:b4e8/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::7cd3:8d7f:5c27:27d0/64
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and

`/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

how do I solve this issue?

Comment: *"I know that a while back I setup a static IP"* - Elaborate here.  Is one of the IP addresses the static one you set up? Because the obvious solution in that case would be to undo what you did "a while back".  If the two IP addresses you are referring are `10.10.10.42/24` and `10.10.10.110/24` - these are local addresses, so this is a problem that exists within your local network.  Your DNS servers look like they might be messed up as well, because only one of them is an actual Public DNS server (`8.8.8.8`) - the others are on the local net.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Speicifically your primary DNS of `10.10.10.110` is almost certainly wrong, unless you have a local DNS server at that address.

Comment: @Nmath OP is running `dnsmasq`.

Comment: @heynnema : Yes, it would make sense for the gateway `10.10.10.1` to be listed as a DNS address, but if there is no device whatsoever at `10.10.10.110`? - and this is also the primary DNS server

Comment: @Nmath Look at IP4.ADDRESS[2]

Comment: It sounds like you're actually running Ubuntu Desktop, not Ubuntu Server... or, you've installed a GUI on Ubuntu Server, as your wired connection is called "Wired connection 1". Which is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112698/discussion-between-nmath-and-heynnema).